# ¿Como recargo el recaptcha v2 de google cuando es success por ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Quiero que al ser exitoso el envio de un formulario con recaptcha v2, se recargue para volver a usarlo mediante ajax sin tener que recargar la pagina

Comment: y que haz intentado, si no muestras avance la pregunta será mal recibida por la comunidad

Comment: grecaptcha.reload();//segundo con este metodo recarga pero no me funciona

Comment: ¿Puedes poner más código? Sólo con una línea es imposible sacar nada en claro...

Comment: Ok, tengo esto https://codepen.io/DanielGeek/pen/aYERyy

Comment: Todo funciona bien, aún falta código pero solo me falta eso que recargue al enviar correctamente el recaptcha